# Getting around const'ness of a C++ method in derived class

Tags: c++, constants, overloading

I have to use a framework which defines an important hook method as const, like this

```
class FrameworkClass {
  ...
  virtual void OnEventA(unsigned value) const;
  ...
}
```

In my derived class I have to save the value that I get through the hook

```
class MyClass: public FrameworkClass
{
  ...
  virtual void OnEventA(unsigned value) const { savedValue = value; } // error!

private:
  unsigned savedValue;
}
```

Unfortunately I can't change the framework.

Is there a good way to get around the const'ness of the hook method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mutable` is too "broad" workaround because affects methods that use const'ness correctly. to workaround inappropriate const'ness there's `const_cast`:

```
class MyClass: public FrameworkClass
{
  ...
  virtual void OnEventA(unsigned value) const { const_cast<MyClass*>(this)->savedValue = value; } // error!

private:
  unsigned savedValue;
}
```

Comment: const_cast is definitly an option. I would not call using mutable too "broad", but rather mentioning that const_cast clearly shows that a function changes state it's not really is supposed to change while mutable indicates that a member can be changed even by const-functions. The latter is especially useful for caching mechanisms.

Comment: For this to be valid, you have to be sure that the method is called on a non-const object. I don't think there's a way to find out if it is so from OnEventA.

Comment: @larsm: by "broad" I meant that it affects not only `OnEventA()` but also all other methods

Comment: But `const_cast` should be used carefully, because it could cause segmentation fault. I avoid using it for this reason.

Answer (score 7):

Make the variable mutable:
`mutable unsigned savedValue;`

Comment: It should be pointed out that whilst this works, `mutable` is really designed for things that form part of the *bitwise* state of the object, rather than the *logical* state, i.e. they won't affect the observable behaviour of the object if they change.  Examples include internal caches, lazy-evaluation schemes, reference counting, etc.